# What could be a second answer to this direction puzzle?

Tags: mathematics

What's a second answer? Here's what I have:

Pamela's pony is lying exactly north of Becky's bicycle. Alycia's action figure is exactly south of Michelle's stuffed mouse. Pamela's pony is exactly east of Michelle's stuffed mouse.

1. In what direction from Becky's bicycle is Alycia's action figure?
2. Think about and write about a different answer.

Comment: Welcome to Puzzling, take our [tour]! Could you please provide [proper attribution](https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7259/proper-attribution-for-non-original-puzzles-a-guide) for this question?

Comment: Hint: the question doesn't specify the distances between objects.

Answer (score 2):

Since the puzzle doesn't specify any distances, the following are all valid arrangements:

> The action figure is directly west of the bike
>  `M P`
>  `A B`

> The action figure is to the north-west of the bike
>  `M P`
>  `A`  
>    `B`

> The action figure is to the south-west of the bike
>  `M P`
>    `B`
>  `A`

> You can make the action figure and bike have any relative north-south distance, but at least in local geography you can't change the fact that the action figure is somewhere to the west of the bike. If you get into curved geography, though, you could have the action figure and bike both be at the South Pole and hence be in the same location.

Answer (score 1):

Obvious answer is "west". It will be looking like this:

```
M P
A B
```

Different answer

> involves Earth's curvature. With big enough distance between objects and close enough to one of the Poles answer may change.